# How can I add custom buttons to the camera screen using the xam.plugin.media nuget (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I am using the xam.plugin.media nuget to record videos I would like to add overlapping buttons at the top of the screen (like snapchat where a user can click into their account profile using the button on the top left corner).

Currently for testing purposes I have a button on my view that when clicked will show the camera. Here is the code that is executed when I click the button:

```
try
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var options = new StoreVideoOptions()
    {
        DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front,
        CompressionQuality = 50
    };

    using (var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(options))
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Process file
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

I'm guessing I will need to make a custom renderer for this. If this is the case can I still use the nuget or will I have to make the full camera capability on my own? I wasn't able to find much online to guide me through this (I was searching for ways to accomplish this using the plugin). While I know this is possible in iOS according to the docs I am also looking to do this in Android.

Comment: this is explicitly covered in the docs: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#take-photo-overlay-ios-only

Comment: Ya the issue is that it is only for iOS I was looking to do this in both iOS and Android. I guess I should have mentioned that in the question I will update that.

Comment: Hi , I think you need to make the full camera capability by using custom renderer . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I think your right, yesterday I stumbled on some of the closed issues posted on the plugins page and James Montemagno was responding that its not possible because on android it launches an external app for the camera. He did mention that it it would be possible with the Camera2 api. But like you said I would have to make it myself.